# Integrate rational function with multiple complex roots

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I want to integrate
$$
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} dx.
$$
By [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%5E2%2F%281%2Bn%5E2*x%5E2%29%5E2%20dx%2C%20x%3D-1..1) I know the solution is
$$
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} dx = \frac{\arctan(n) - \frac{n}{n^2+1}}{n^3}.
$$
Do derive it on my own, I did a partial fraction decomposition and found
$$
 \frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2n^2}}{1+n^2x^2} + \frac{\frac{1}{4n^2}}{(x-i/n)^2} + \frac{\frac{1}{4n^2}}{(x+i/n)^2}. 
$$
I checked this multiple times, but it must be wrong, because when I proceed with it I get
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} dx
  & = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1+n^2x^2} d x + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x-i/n)^2} d x + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(x+i/n)^2} d x \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2}\left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{\arctan(xn)}{n}\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 + \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{-1}{x-i/n}\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 + \frac{-1}{x+i/n}\bigg\vert_{-1}^1 \right)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \frac{\arctan(n)}{n} + \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{-2}{1+1/n^2} + \frac{-2}{1+1/n^2}\right)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \frac{\arctan(n)}{n} -\frac{1}{1+1/n^2} \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \frac{\arctan(n)}{n} - \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right) \\
& = \frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^2+1}
\end{align*}
This result is consistent which what I found with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%280.5%2Fn%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bn%5E2x%5E2%29%20%2B%20%280.25%2Fn%5E2%29%2F%28x%2Bi%2Fn%29%5E2%20%2B%20%280.25%2Fn%5E2%29%2F%28x-i%2Fn%29%5E2%20dx), but surely
$$
 \frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^2+1} \ne \frac{\arctan(n) - \frac{n}{n^2+1}}{n^3}
$$
so what went wrong, I am sitting here since hours and do not see any fault...

Comment: Guess: The conjugate rule: $(1-i/n)(1+i/n)=1+1/n^2$. I think you write that it is $1-1/n^2$ at a step.

Comment: @mickep: Yes, this was wrong. I edited it, but this does not change the problem, the derived expression is still different then what it should be.

Comment: Well, then I guess your partial fraction is incorrect. The last two terms should be divided by $n^2$, it seems.

Comment: @mickep: Yes, this was the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid multiple complex conjugate roots, you can use the formula in [Application to symbolic integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Application_to_symbolic_integration)
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}
  &=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{Ax+B}{1+n^2x^2}\right]+\frac{Cx+D}{1+n^2x^2}\\
  &=\frac{Cn^2x^3+(D-A)n^2x^2+(C-2Bn^2)x+(D+A)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}
\end{align}
so that
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
A&=-\frac{1}{2n^2}\\
B&=0\\
C&=0\\
D&=+\frac{1}{2n^2}
\end{align}
\right.
$$
and the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int\frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}dx
  &=\frac{Ax+B}{1+n^2x^2}+\int\frac{Cx+D}{1+n^2x^2}dx\\
  &=-\frac{x}{2n^2(1+n^2x^2)}+\frac{1}{2n^2}\int\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}dx\\
  &=-\frac{x}{2n^2(1+n^2x^2)}+\frac{1}{2n^3}\arctan(nx)+c
\end{align}

Comment: I do not understand. In your first line, how could $$ \frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} = D\left[ \frac{Ax + B}{1+n^2x^2}\right] + \frac{Cx + D}{1+n^2x^2} $$ for $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb R$, if I add the right part the denominator is $1+n^2x^2 \ne (1+n^2x^2)$? Even if I read it as $$ D\left[ \frac{Ax + B}{1+n^2x^2}\right] + \frac{Cx + D}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} $$ is is not equal your third line $\frac{Cn^2x^3+(D-A)n^2x^2+(C-2Bn^2)x+(D+A)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$ (for example where does $Cn^2x^3$ come from)?

Comment: @Stefan: sorry, the $D$ was intended as a derivative. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Ok, makes perfect sense now :)

Comment: Clever!  I've never seen that trick before.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to check this.  Let

$$f(m) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1+m x^2}  = \frac{2}{m} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1/m+x^2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}\arctan \sqrt{m}$$

$$f'(m) = -\int_{-1}^1 dx \frac{x^2}{(1+m x^2)^2}  = -m ^{-3/2} \arctan{\sqrt{m}} + \frac1{m (1+m)}$$

Your integral is thus

$$-f'(n^2) = \frac{\arctan{n}}{n^3} - \frac1{n^2 (1+n^2)} $$

Comment: Nice calculation!

Answer (score 2):

You have a strange form for your partial fraction decomposition.  I would be inclined to stay in the field of real numbers and write:
$$
\frac{x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} = \frac{Ax+B}{1+n^2x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}
$$
It turns out $B=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $D = -\frac{1}{n^2}$, while $A=C=0$.

To integrate $\int\frac{dx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$, use the substitution $nx=\tan\theta$.   Then $n\,dx = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta$ and $(1+n^2x^2)^{\color{green}{2}} = \sec^4\theta$.  You get
\begin{align*}
    \int\frac{dx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} &= \frac{1}{n}\int\frac{\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{\sec^4\theta} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \int\cos^2\theta\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2n} \int(1+ \cos(2\theta))\,d\theta\\
&= \frac{\theta}{2n} + \frac{1}{4n}\sin(2\theta) + C \\
&= \frac{\arctan(nx)}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}\sin\theta \cos\theta + C \\
&= \frac{\arctan(nx)}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}\frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} + C \\
&= \frac{\arctan(nx)}{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2} + C \\
\end{align*}

[Green exponent of $2$ added thanks to Stefan's careful eye.]

Comment: I am going through all my calculations now, and I guess there is the fault as mickep pointed out. I found this form of the partial fraction in a book, your form is known to me too, but I am not sure how to integrate $$ \frac{1}{(1+ax^2)^2} $$ so I did not used this form.

Comment: I die a little inside whenever I see those trigonometric substitutions. How students will ever learn to integrate the general rational function if that is how they are taught the case $\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$?

Comment: I read that $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$, so then we would have $1+n^2x^2 = 1+(nx)^2 = 1+\tan^2(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta) \ne \sec^4(\theta)$ with your substitution, so why then $1+n^2x^2 = \sec^4\theta$?

Comment: @Stefan: forgot a power of two.  See edit.  Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Yes, now it is clear :) Let me add that $\sec x = 1/\cos(x)$ is used a lot.